# Unable to successfully save umbraco content changes

Tags: umbraco, webmatrix

Has anyone come across the problem whereby Umbraco says content changes have been saved successfully, you close everything down (including webmatrix), only to go back in and find that the changes have been lost?

I'm working on my localhost.

I think it's to do with caching of data on webmatrix, but I haven't a clue how you'd start up `http://localhost:xyz` without using webmatrix (if only to rule it out of the equation).

Answer (score 2):

I believe when the message displays, the changes will be stored in database and next time you open your Umbraco for some reason, the XML file does not sync with database. In order to force it to be synced, simply delete the Umbraco.config file and restart WebMatrix and re-open the Umbraco.

The main advantage of using Webmatrix for Umbraco is it's IISExpress. So if you want to work with Umbraco without Webmatrix, add your website to IIS directly and since then you can have access to your site.

Comment: I deleted the Umbraco.config, and sure it helps, but still not every change to the DB are commited on restart of the IIS Express.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a mystery problem still happening in SQL CE, for both WebMatrix and Visual Studio users alike. See the ongoing discussion in the umbraco issue tracker for more information at http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4621